# How to test a class which extends Thread

Tags: java, testing, junit4

Java methods can be tested using assertions like assertEquals(*,*), asssertTrue(_) in jUnit 4. How do I use assertions to test something like this:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public int val;

    public MyThread(int val){
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
         // doSomeWork(); 
    }
}
```

Also, do I need to wait for run() to finish executing before jUnit returns the test results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most important things first: It's generally considered better design not to inherit where unnecessary. It's usually the case that better designed code is easier to test.

The simplest possible way to test the existing code is to call `run` instead of `start`. If you want to keep the thread you can call `Thread.join` to wait for completion. You may want to call `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` to report any unchecked exception from the thread.